# Is there a way to show the PowerPoint language dialog programatically?

Tags: powerpoint, vsto

In a VSTO add-in I'm creating for PowerPoint I'm trying to show the language selector dialog and read the results from it.

[image: Language dialoag]

In Word it seems you would do it using

```
Word.Dialog dlg = Application.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFormatDefineStyleLang];
dlg.Show();
```

but I don't see similar functionality in PowerPoint (no PowerPoint "sibling" to wdWordDialog).

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in 2010 - please see this post

PowerPoint Open "Record Slide Show" Dialog and detect if Presentation has a recording c# addin

You will need to find the equivalent for "RecordNarration" but it should work for you.

There is nothing special in VSTO that can do it for you, you will have to use wpf/winform, you may have a look at fontdialog class

Comment: OK, turns out the command then is
``` lang-cs
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("SetLanguage");
```
But it doesn't block my code while the dialog is open, so I don't know when the dialog closes. I also don't know how to read the values the user chose. Do you happen to know how?